# Django and React authentications system

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-registration

I am intermediate Django web developer. I am trying my hands on working with both Django and react at the same time. It's all good if you are using the rest framework, but I am stuck with the authentication system. I love Django built-in `UserCreationForm` but the solutions(JWT) I find don't seem to utilize Django forms.

I tried `Django Djoser`  and `Knox`; my problem Djoser throw parse error when the password is complex, i.e. include symbols, and both don't utilize Django forms.

**Note:**

1. It's okay if your solution does utilize Django forms, but it's better if it does.
2. I should be able to login to Django admin panel too.
3. I should be able to upload images(profile pic) while registering user.

And that's it any help is really appreciated and also English is not my first language, so forgive me if I made any mistake.

**Thanks**

Comment: Just follow this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/uZgRbnIsgrA

the best one for your problem in my opinion

Comment: thanks mate let me check